# How to store form data with single key and multiple values via POST API call

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to store form data in a way, where there be same key but different values separated by `,` (comma). I am able to send form data via `POST` for single "key/value" pair but not for a "key/multiple(values)" pair.

Please share your inputs on the same.

```
 async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        let url = "https://api/slef_domain/assign_dId/?";
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("sourcedomainID", this.state.sourceDomID);
        form.append("destInfra", this.state.destInID);
        form.append("destdomainID", this.state.destDomID);
        form.append("domainRangeId", this.state.domainRanID);

        // Figure out the way to append the data in form : SOMETHING LIKE BELOW DEPENDING UPON 
        // THE TIMES USER ADDED THOSE ROWS BEFORE SUBMITTING THE FORM
        // form.append("sourcedomainID", this.state.sourceDomID);
        // form.append("destInfra", this.state.destInID);
        // form.append("destdomainID", this.state.destDomID);

        // Here we use the FETCH method to POST data and display the response back on Web.
        await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: form,
            headers: { "Authorization": `Token ${token}` },
            "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
        }).then((results) => {
            return results
        }).then(response => {
            console.log("Actual Response: ", response)
            if (response.status === 204) {
                console.log("Response 204: ", response)
                this.setState({ alertMessage: "Success" })
            }
            else {
                console.log("Response no code: ", response)
                this.setState({ alertMessage: "Unavailable" })
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you share what the `state` look like? and remember that a `key` must be unique, if you want to add multiple values to a `key`, you should use an `array` or other data type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use this one if you are using PHP on your server(based on the MDN's [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example)):

```js
form.append('arr[]', 'value1');
form.append('arr[]', 'value2');
```

or just use:

```js
var arr = ['value1', 'value2'];

form.append('arr', JSON.stringify(arr));
```

and then `JSON.parse` to retrieve your array

Comment: Thank you, currently my development server is having some issues, I will test it this way and update you back!

Comment: It does work, when I try to add Static values in array. I am facing another issue before that which is "onChange" method is not adding target.value in an array. Working on it. Thank you for your inputs though!

Comment: Why do we JSON.stringify the array?
can you please explain the solution

Comment: This is due to the `FormData.append()` value parameter requirements. You can only pass certain types, and string is one of them. So in order to pass our JavaScript object we first need to convert it to a JSON string. More about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Syntax under parameters section.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for explaining and sharing the link!